# Firebase gets stuck when reading too much data

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If my node.js server tries to read too much data - the firebase client would start emitting the error messages as shown below to the stderr.

It doesn't seem right my app just gets stuck and the promise to get the data would never be succeeded nor rejected.

Have you ever seen this? Is there a workaround may be? Thanks!

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE INTERNAL ERROR: Server Error: The specified payload is too large, please request a location with less data.
>   @firebase/database: FIREBASE INTERNAL ERROR: Server Error: The specified payload is too large, please request a location with less data. 
>       ...

Comment: I have seen this error when trying to read branches that have a lot of data.  Try switching to a query with pagination or perhaps iterating over children using a `child_added` listener instead of reading the whole branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase realtime database, you can do some indexing on your firebase db to prevent loading all data on your server when doing queries and also you can start with firebase pagination using `startAt` method